# How does an Azure Active Directory app registration establish trust?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) state:

> Registering your application establishes a trust relationship between your app and the Microsoft identity platform. The trust is unidirectional: your app trusts the Microsoft identity platform, and not the other way around.

What exactly is meant by "trust" here and how does the app registration establish said trust?

The way I understand it the registration basically makes the app known to the AD, but how does that make the AD, the app is redirecting to for interactive logins, more trust-worthy to the app? Couldn't a malicious AD just pretend to know any app that's using it for logins? Wouldn't it need some kind of shared secret to assure the app that the AD really is the AD? And isn't HTTPS establishing that trust already?

It makes more sense to me the other way around: the AD receives a login request along with a redirect URI set by the app. But if the redirect URI is not known to the AD then the request is not trust-worthy and will be rejected.

I'm probably misunderstanding something, so could someone please explain the idea behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In authentication world trust is a complicated word. In my opinion, the easiest way to approach this thing is taking the **Google Sign-In -button** as an example. You can use it to log in with your Google account on almost every website out there. Does this mean Google **trusts** every website out there using it? No, of course not. Do those websites **trust** Google? Sure they do, they have no visibility if Google returns the correct information about the users to them.

The case is very similar here as in most cases you will be using the same protocol to implement it (OAuth2 OIDC).

You are correct, you need to configure secrets & returnUrls to make sure that the App Registration is not used for malicious purposes, however, this does not create trust between the identity provider and the application. It's just technical measures to protect the client.

However, you can of course trust the application if you want to. The most common way is to grant it access to [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis) so the application can do actions on behalf of the user. Usually this is done by those **consent screens** you probably know ("grant access to your email and phone number"). In enterprise setting, they are often omitted and access is granted with [admin constent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc).

TL;DR; There is no inherit trust just because there is an App Registration, however you can trust an app to access user data.